# 仮想マシン上のWebサーバにホストからアクセスできない

Tags: network, virtualbox, rust

Rustの勉強のため，簡単なWebサーバのプログラムを書いています．

VirtualBox上のArch Linuxをサーバとして用い，http://nickel.rs/のHello Worldを`cargo run`で実行しました．ところが，http://127.0.0.1:portにゲストOS側からアクセスすることはできても，http://guest_ip:portにホストOS側のブラウザからアクセスすることができません．http://ironframework.io/も試してみましたが，同じくアクセスはできませんでした．

ここで，ネットワークの問題を疑い，ゲスト側で`python -m http.server`を実行したところ，今度はホスト側からアクセスすることができました．ネットワークが問題ではないのでしょうか？

VirtualBoxはブリッジアダプターでネットワークと繋がっており，ホストから`ping`を打ったり，`ssh`で接続することはできます．`rustc`のバージョンは`rustc 1.0.0 (built 2015-06-01)`で，`cargo`はAURのcargo-binを使用していてバージョンは`cargo 0.3.0-nightly (47306a4 2015-06-17) (built 2015-06-18)`です．

一体どうすればRustで書いたサーバにアクセスできるでしょうか．

Comment: ゲストOSで `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`してポート80のIPを調べてみてください。

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi  `ss -an|grep LISTEN`を実行したものの，ポート80番の行がありませんでした．

Comment: portが6767 ならそちらを見ないとだめです。

Comment: server.listenで指定したIPアドレスがそのまま表示されています．

Comment: で、その値の内容は?という話なのですが、すでに回答は出ていますね。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

127.0.0.1にbindしても、ローカルホストからしか接続できないことがあります。
ソースコード中でアドレスを記載している部分、

```
   server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
```

これを、eth0などのネットワークインターフェイスが持つIPアドレス、または0.0.0.0を指定してみてはどうでしょうか。

```
   server.listen("0.0.0.0:6767");
```

Comment: アドレスをenp0s8にした場合は'Could not parse socket address'と言われて実行できませんでした．しかし，0.0.0.0や，サーバのIPを指定するとホストからうまく接続できました．
0.0.0.0ならば接続できるのはなぜか，理由を書いていただけませんか．

Comment: 0.0.0.0はそのPCが持っているIP全部でLISTENするという意味だからです。netstat -anで見て欲しかったのは、まさにこの0.0.0.0です。これが127.0.0.1だったりすると、ローカルホストのみのループバックなので外部から接続できません。

Comment: すいません、ネットワークインタフェースと書いたのは、ネットワークインタフェースのアドレスという意味でした。回答の文言も後で直しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

ホスト側からアクセスする際のゲストのIPアドレスが`192.168.1.2`だった場合、以下のようにすればアクセスできます。

```
server.listen("192.168.1.2:6767");
```